# casting String to JSONObject

Tags: java, casting, json

I have a json response from server, I get as string, and want to cast to JSONObject (import org.json.JSONObject;)

this is my casting:

```
 JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
```

and this is what I get:

```
responseString = {"code":0,"type":"success","description":null,"data":{"path":"http:........"}}
responseJson = {"class":"class java.lang.StringBuilder"}
```

does anyone knows why is responseJson not with correct values?
I can do

```
responseJson.getString("class")
```

but what I want to do is

```
responseJson.getString("type")
```

Comment: Can you try `JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString.toString());`?

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example. Sample input and sample output.

Comment: You cannot use "cast" to change the type of an object.  (What you're using is a constructor -- one that "parses" the JSON.)

Comment: (And your above "example" is bogus.  There is no way that the value in `responseJson` came from parsing `responseString`.)  (Unless ...  `responseString` is already parsed and doesn't need to be further parsed.)

Comment: Try this:  responseJson = responseString;

Comment: Show us the declaration and initialization of `responseString`.  My guess it that it's a JSONObject, not a String.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry, responseString really is NOT a string, it's a StringBuilder.
this worked:
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString.toString());

Answer (score 1):

Try this way with [json-simple](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1)

```
String jsonString = "{\"code\":0,\"type\":\"success\",\"description\":null,\"data\":
                                                      {\"path\":\"http:........\"}}";
org.json.simple.JSONObject json =(org.json.simple.JSONObject) new JSONParser()
                                                             .parse(jsonString); 
System.out.println(json.get("data"));
```